# Crystal report error Load report failed after 2-3 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report 13 on my web server.

It works fine but after 2-3 days it troughs error `Load report failed.`.

After getting error I've restarted IIS and it starts working fine again.

Crystal report troughs this error after 2-3 days.

Can any one tell me why I'm getting this error and why after restarting IIS error is gone.

What is the issue with crystal report and how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally my problem is solved.

I just changed Recycling time interval from 1740 to 1000 of application pool.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Can u elaborate this issue?? And how to change the recycling time interval??